# Full video in VrvideoView for Cardboard

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I try to modify google sample "samples-simplevideowidge", for see the video in full screen automatically. But I can't.

I need create a empty activity, only with a video 360.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly full screen mode with

```
vrVideoView.setDisplayMode(VrWidgetView.DisplayMode.FULLSCREEN_MONO);
```

in any initial or construction method

Comment: hello #ekad is it possible to help me in carbord sdk for native integration?